# PHP How to check Json

Tags: php, json, api

I would like to make a if cicle, who control a json.
This file json is a request from a function, I would like to control and stop it when it doesn't contains anything.

I Tried , using the json_decode and controlling the array
and I've tried with the code below, but the result is this "[]"

```
<?php

function myFunc($hnd , $url){ 

curl_setopt ($hnd, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json');
        $json= curl_exec($hnd);
        if($json['']==''){
              echo "ERROR";
        }else{
              return $json;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved in this way :

```
  if(!isset($obj['array']){
            echo "Error" ! ";
            die;
    }else{ //continue
```